# Detect a cycle of 3 adjacent vertices in a graph represented by a linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity, graph-theory

Given an undirected graph with more edges than vertices and represented with a linked list of adjacent vertices. How would one go about detecting whether a cycle of 3 adjacent vertices exists and what would be the time complexity?

Example graph:

```
1->2->5
2->3->1->4
3->2->4
4->2->5->3
5->1->4
```

A cycle of 3 adjacent vertices exists `2->3->4->2`

Comment: Hello! This is a Q&A website about programming. For questions like this one, you'd better ask on https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: How is `2->3->4->2` a solution? There seems to be no edge from `3` to `4`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved, using the algorithm **Depth first search**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
const int maximumSize=40;
vector<vector<int>> visited(maximumSize, vector<int>(maximumSize, 0));
vector<int> graph[maximumSize], closedContour, temporary;
int vertices, edges;
set<vector<int>> contours;
void showContentSetVector(set<vector<int>> input)
{
    for(auto iterator=input.begin(); iterator!=input.end(); ++iterator)
    {
        for(auto item : *iterator)
        {
            cout<<item<<", ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return;
}
bool compare(int i,int j)
{
    return (i<j);
}
void createGraph()
{
    cin>>vertices>>edges;
    int vertex0, vertex1;
    for(int i=1; i<=edges; ++i)
    {
        cin>>vertex0>>vertex1;
        graph[vertex0].push_back(vertex1);
        graph[vertex1].push_back(vertex0);
    }
    return;
}
void depthFirstSearch(int initial, int current, int previous)
{
    if(visited[initial][current]==1)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<temporary.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(temporary[i]==current)
            {
                for(int j=i; j<temporary.size(); ++j)
                {
                    closedContour.push_back(temporary[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        sort(closedContour.begin(), closedContour.end(), compare);
        contours.insert(closedContour);
        closedContour.clear();
        return;
    }
    visited[initial][current]=1;
    temporary.push_back(current);
    for(int next : graph[current])
    {
        if(next==previous)
        {
            continue;
        }
        depthFirstSearch(initial, next, current);
    }
    temporary.pop_back();
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    createGraph();
    for(int vertex=1; vertex<=vertices; ++vertex)
    {
        temporary.clear();
        depthFirstSearch(vertex, vertex, -1);
    }
    cout<<"contours <- ";
    showContentSetVector(contours);
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
contours <- 
1: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
2: 1, 2, 4, 5, 
3: 2, 3, 4,
```

As you can see among of the provided cycles (closed contours) there is that contour, you mentined in your problem, consisiting of **3 adjacent vertices**: `vertices={2, 3, 4}`.

Because of you mentioned that your **graph is undirected** I think your example graph must look like:

```
1:[2, 5],
2:[1, 3, 4],
3:[2, 4],
4:[2, 3, 5],
5:[1, 4].
```